# Вставка строк из таблицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Помогите реализовать запрос на вставку строк. Создается новая таблица

```
zone_id | item_id | action_date | price
```

необходим запрос из другой таблицы (эти столбцы присутствуют), который добавит по одной строке на первое число каждого месяца (период 2012-2016) для конкретного товара (item_id), при условии что за месяц цена на один товар может меняться и необходимо записать только последнее изменение цены.
т.е. к примеру есть 2 записи за месяц

```
1 | 0001 | 2012.9.12 | 300
1 | 0001 | 2012.9.29 | 450
```

в данном примере при вставке строки в новую таблицу с датой 2012.10.01 должна добавиться цена 450, так как это последнее изменение в этом месяце.

Буду благодарен любой помощи, хочется разобраться в этом вопросе

Comment: *на первое число каждого месяца* А если присутствует запись за первое число месяца - она учитывается как цена на это число? иными словами - на 0:00 первого числа или на 24:00?

Comment: хороший вопрос, в тз ничего не сказано по этому поводу. 
но с другой стороны, когда в системе наступает первое число и в этот момент появляется запись об изменении цены на товар, то в данном случае, мне кажется, что раньше произошло (новая запись или новый месяц) по тому сценарию и пойдет. либо как последнее изменение за прошедший период, либо уже в новом месяце

Comment: *в тз ничего не сказано по этому поводу.* Имхо надо уточнить у заказчика. В крайнем случае я бы считал по состоянию на ноль часов - т.е. не учитывать. Это более логично, наверное...

Answer (score 2):

Создадим таблицы и заполним данными:

```
create table t1(zone_id int, item_id varchar(10), action_date date,price money)
create table t2(zone_id int, item_id varchar(10), action_date date,price money)

insert into t1
values
(1,'0001','2012-09-12',300),
(1,'0001','2012-09-29',450),
(1,'0001','2012-10-05',425),
(1,'0001','2012-10-17',460),
(1,'0001','2012-10-25',462),
(1,'0001','2012-11-17',415),
(1,'0001','2012-11-30',410),
(1,'0002','2012-09-11',600),
(1,'0002','2012-09-15',590),
(1,'0002','2012-09-30',625),
(1,'0002','2012-10-10',630),
(1,'0002','2012-11-17',605),
(1,'0002','2012-11-28',610),
(2,'0001','2012-09-15',295),
(2,'0001','2012-09-27',455),
(2,'0001','2012-10-04',430),
(2,'0001','2012-10-15',460),
(2,'0001','2012-10-25',461),
(2,'0001','2012-11-19',415),
(2,'0001','2012-11-30',410),
(2,'0002','2012-09-12',610),
(2,'0002','2012-09-15',590),
(2,'0002','2012-09-29',625),
(2,'0002','2012-10-10',625),
(2,'0002','2012-11-17',605),
(2,'0002','2012-11-30',615)
```

Сам запрос:

```
insert into t2(zone_id,item_id,action_date,price)
select zone_id,item_id,action_date,price
from(
select zone_id, 
       item_id, 
       action_date,
       price,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by zone_id, item_id,datepart(YEAR,action_date),datepart(MONTH,action_date) order by action_date desc) as nn
from t1) as a
where nn=1
```

Получим по одной цене для каждого товара для каждой зоны на каждый месяц.

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно! Добавил условия для периода и id товара и все отлично вставилось. Из примера понял, что надо поближе познакомится с OVER и всему прилегающему.
Посоветуете добротной литературы с примерами посложнее по данной тематике?

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так

```
INSERT INTO
    `some_table` (`zone_id`,`item_id`,`action_date`, `price`)
SELECT
    `src`.`zone_id`,
    `src`.`item_id`,
    `src`.`action_date`,
    `src`.`price` 
FROM
    `some_table_two`  AS `src`
ORDER BY `src`.`action_date`
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!
но как быть со вставкой именно первого дня месяца в столбец даты, если к примеру в основной таблицы нет записи за первое число месяца?
Т.е., как я понял, берем товар, вставляем в строку первое значение с датой 1.1.2012, а затем выбираем из основной таблицы последнее изменение значение цены за период <= 1.1.2012, и так для каждого месяца (второе будет с условием для февраля <= 1.2.2012 и так с каждым месяцем до конца периода 2016г). Вот как это записать в один запрос не понятно

Comment: у вас бд mssql ?

Comment: да, 2012 года
сложность заключается в выборе последнего изменения цены за месяц, на ум приходит только использование max(action_date) и как потом все это связать в цикл выборки и заполнения по дням нового месяца